# Cannot convert lambda expression, works in one project, not another

Tags: c#

I have two projects that I have defined CountriesCollection below as an ObservableCollection, in one I keep getting an error, but the same code works fine in the other project.

```
    public ObservableCollection<Country> CountriesCollection { get; set; }
```

in the constructor, I do a CountriesCollection = Utils.GetCountries();  (do I need to new ObservableCollection() ?)

which returns an ObservableCollection of Country

```
public class Country
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

in the main project (that this doesn't work), the intellisense is showing p as an item.

```
var index = CountriesCollection.IndexOf(p => p.Key == clientProfileResponse.User.CountryCode);
```

[image]

whereas in the (test - just to test this issue) project that this does work, I am seeing p as a predicate.

[image]

In both projects the Using System.Linq is grayed out. I can't tell what the difference is and how to get this to work in my main project.

I am able to do this in the main project, but still unclear why the IndexOf doesn't work.

```
                    SelectedCountry =
                        CountriesCollection.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Key == clientProfileResponse.User.CountryCode);
```

Ultimately, I just want to get the index of the Country via the Key.

UPDATE:
Here is the working project https://file.io/nlx58Tf2

Comment: I am not aware of any BCL `IndexOf` method taking `Func<T,bool>` as a parameter. I may be wrong, or someone has written an *extension method*. Inspect the method, see where it comes from, question answered

Comment: So how come it works in one project and not the other?

Comment: Like @MichaelRandall said, find if there is an extension method named "IndexOf" in the project where it works

Comment: Its a vanilla Xamarin Forms project, I don't see an extension for IndexOf. I uploaded the project here that works in the main post.